# AJAX: пустой $_FILES

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Здравствуйте! Отправляю файл на сервер (локальный: vertrigo(apache)) с помощью AJAX и drag & drop HTML5. Файл записывается в папку, на страницу с AJAX возвращается ответ. Но если после выполнения AJAX перейти на страницу с php-скриптом, то массив $_FILES будет пустым.

index.html

```
<form action="upload_file.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" class="test-form" id="tForm">
  <!-- <input type="file" class="inp-file" name="file1" id="iFile"> -->
  <input type="text" class="inp-file" name="textF" value="test">
  <input type="submit" name="butSubmit" id="butSubmit" value="Отправить">
</form>
<div id="dnd" class="dnd"></div>
```

main.js

```
var form = document.getElementById( 'tForm' );
var inpFile = document.getElementById( 'iFile' );
var butSubmit = document.getElementById( 'butSubmit' );
var dnd = document.getElementById( 'dnd' );
var dropFiles = null;
var data = new FormData( form );
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
data.append( 'par', 'val' );
xhr.open( 'POST', 'php.php', true );
xhr.send( data );
dnd.ondragstart = function(e){
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
console.log( 'dragstart' );
}

dnd.ondragenter = function(e){
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
console.log( 'dragenter' );
}

dnd.ondragover = function(e){
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
console.log( 'dragover' );
}

dnd.ondragleave = function(e){
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
console.log( 'dragleave' );
}

dnd.ondrag = function(e){
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
console.log( 'drag' );
}

dnd.ondragend = function(e){
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
console.log( 'dragend' );
}

dnd.ondrop = function(e){
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
dropFiles = e.dataTransfer.files;
console.log( 'drop--- ' + dropFiles[0]['name'] );
data.append( 'azaza', dropFiles[0] );
}

form.onsubmit = function( e ){
  e.preventDefault();
  xhr.open( 'POST', 'upload_file.php', true );
  xhr.send( data );
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState != 4) return;
    if (this.status != 200) {
    alert( 'ошибка: ' + (this.status ? this.statusText : 'запрос не удался') );  
    return;
  }

  console.log( this.responseText );
  form.submit();
  }
}
```

upload_files.php

```
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["azaza"]["tmp_name"], "u/" . $_FILES["azaza"]["name"] );
print_r( $_FILES );
echo '<br>';
echo $_FILES["azaza"]["name"];
```

Спасибо!

Comment: `Но если после выполнения AJAX перейти на страницу с php-скриптом, то массив $_FILES будет пустым.` - а почему там что-то должно отображаться при прямом обращении?

Comment: Если просто отправлять форму (без ajax), то мы попадаем на страницу .php и там массив не пустой, а при отправке через ajax, если затем перейти на страницу .php — массив пуст. Почему? Я только начал изучать ajax и php, так что извиняюсь за глупый вопрос.

Comment: В том то и дело, что одно дело *отправлять форму* (неважно через ajax или без), а другое дело напрямую просто обратиться к скрипту. Логично, что когда ты обращаешься сразу напрямую к нему, то не происходит никакой отправки формы и там ничего нет........ какую задачу ты решаешь и почему тебе не хватает ответа, которые приходит от сервера? или это и был самый главный вопрос - почему ничего нет?)

Comment: Задача: загрузить файлы на сервер, ответа хватает. Но вопрос, действительно, в том, почему если после ajax-запроса обратиться к php там ничего не будет. Понимаю, что ничего не понимаю )

Comment: Ну вот на счет того, почему нет ничего - я написал выше.  нет отправки формы на *данной* странице, поэтому и пустота.